# Denoising of Images capture by digital camera using Butterworth Filter

Tags: filter-design, noise, denoising

Right now, i am doing a research on how the Butterworth filter can reduce the noise in images captured by digital camera. For start, what i need is images which contain noise in it. My question is;

1. Is there is a way to add artificial noise such as gaussian noise into images?
2. After i have an images with noise in it, what are the parameters that i should have to create butterworth lowpass filter?

This is my block diagram of my research. any help will do:

[image: this is my block diagram of my research. any help will do.]

Comment: I am afraid that the way this question is phrased, it is likely that it will be closed. In general, you would first have to load your images, add noise with imnoise (http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html) and then apply the filter at an appropriate spatial frequency depending on the image content and level of noise. Have you tried something so far? Have you produced any code that attempts to deal with the task?

Comment: Right now, i have not done anything yet. I just need to make sure my step is correct. I understood that by using matlab, i can add noise into images, but what i dont understand is from here what parameter should i use?

Comment: Why are you studying this problem? Do you have a practical application in mind?

Comment: This research is for my final year project. What i have in mind is i need a picture captured by digital camera, and then i add noise in it, and then i will apply butterworth lowpass filter through it to remove noise. Is there any wrong with my idea?